# passsing argument to ng-click when using with polymer

Tags: angularjs, polymer-1.0

I am using Polymer with angularjs, i am trying to pass argument to a function called using ng-click, in a polymer's dom-repeat, but ng-click not accepting the argument.
code sample :

```
<!-- index.html -->
    <paper-tabs selected="{{selected}}" attr-for-selected="name" bottom-item>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{items}}" ng-repeat= "iteme in items">
    <paper-tab name="{{item.title}}" ng-click="navigate(iteme.title)" >{{item.title}}</paper-tab>
    </template>
    </paper-tabs>
    </app-toolbar>

<!-- Polymer Array -->
items: {
      type: Array,
      value: function() {
        return [{link : 'contact',title: 'Contact',icon: 'dashboard'},
         {link : 'profile',title: 'Update Profile',icon: 'group'},
         {link : 'pinReset',title: 'Reset Pin',icon: 'message'},
         {link : 'settings',title: 'Settings',icon: 'settings'},
         {link : 'about',title: 'About',icon: 'message'},
         {link : 'logout',title: 'Logout',icon: 'logout'}]
      }
},

<!-- Angular Js controller -->

function MainController($location, $scope) {
var vm = this;
$scope.navigate=function(page) {
console.log(page);//this log returns undefined
 $location.path('/'+page);
 };
```

How can i pass argument to navigate function inside polymer loop

Comment: Can you provide us a Plunker or something to test your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could there be a typo

```
<paper-tab name="{{item.title}}" ng-click="navigate(iteme.title)" >{{item.title}}</paper-tab>
```

I see you using

> item.title

and

> iteme.title